# Remove and replace kitchen window with just caulking outside

Tags: kitchens, windows, removal, remodeling, demolition

I have an old kitchen window and like to replace it with modern double pane glass. Here is the look from inside:

[image]

Here is from outside:

[image]

Do I just remove the caulking from the outside (red box)? Then pop it out or something?

[image]

This is an old window so I don't know how it is mounted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely has a window flange on it that you'll need to remove as well which is probably buried behind the siding. If you have a reciprocating saw you'll probably have to cut the flange off. An alternative that I've seen is to to remove the glass and then collapse the frame pulling nails and all with it. If you don't mind putting a frame around the window then you cut a section of siding off just wide enough to get to the flange, remove everything and then put a frame around the new windows to cover the siding that you removed. You could even save the siding piece your removed and put it in place under the frame.

Comment: I use a skill saw and cut the flange, the new remodel window won't have a flange but screws hold them in place, calking to seal, I have never tried to collapse a frame and think that could damage the siding.

Comment: I've seen this as well but I'd still get the flange on it so you can cut it down to the right size even if that means removing it altogether. Allows 4 less need of caulk and still gives the room needed for adjusting it. If the window opening is not plumb, like most, then the window without flange may have fairly large gaps in spots. The flange would cover those.

Comment: I custom order the windows so they fit like a glove and then they don't have the ugly box aground the window on the outside that doesent match.